# How to have an image display in a twig template and act as a link for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, twig

I have the following code on my website in a .twig file

```
<a href="https://appointments.detailandsupply.com/easyappointments/index.php?service=14" style="color: lightgreen; font-weight: 600; font-size: 18px; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;">Click here to schedule an appointment</a>
```

I have an image named schedule.png located in /files/ and would like to have this display as a link and remove the "Click here to schedule an appointment" text. How do I go about doing so?

I tried adding `<img src="{{ asset('files/schedule.png') }}">` in the section where it says "Click here to schedule an appointment"

Comment: You say that you tried to add the image element inside the link, how did that go? I mean this seems totally correct, what is not working?

Comment: What Drupal version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Edited: Based on the standard Drupal file structure

To display an image as a link in a Drupal Twig template, and

So, if you're referencing an image or any other asset stored in the public file system of a standard Drupal installation, the path would indeed start with /sites/default/files/

So the updated code will be

```
<a href="https://appointments.detailandsupply.com/easyappointments/index.php?service=14" style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/schedule.png" alt="Schedule an appointment" style="border: none;">
    </a>
```

Comment: How would this even solve OP's problem?

Comment: @DarkBee I have edited my answer. Could you please check if that could solve the problem or not?

Comment: Well no, why would OP use a relative/absolute path? The question is why the function `{{ asset(...)  }}` isn't working